# Paginate Wordpress $wpdb Query?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, wordpress

I have this query:

```
    <?php
    $query= "SELECT wposts.* FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'votes' AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' AND wposts.post_type = 'post' ORDER BY CAST(wpostmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC LIMIT 10";
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
    if ($posts ) : foreach ($posts as $post):
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    // Post here 
    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
    </div>
```

I'm using this because Wordpress can't properly order meta_values that uses numbers, anyway...everything works fine except I have no clue on how to paginate this using wp_pagenavi.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I wouldn't recommend it, you could try changing the properties of the global `$wp_query` object.

```
global $wp_query; // shouldn't be required
$query = "SELECT wposts.* FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta 
   WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'votes'
   AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' AND wposts.post_type = 'post' ORDER BY 
   CAST(wpostmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC LIMIT 10";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

$wp_query->posts = $posts;
$wp_query->is_paged = true;
$wp_query->current_post = -1;
// etc etc
```

You can look up the definition of the [WP_Query](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/query.php#L729) class or do a [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) or [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r) on the $wp_query object after calling query_posts.

Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Thank @jaziel matoso,

Below code works:

```php
global $wp_query; 

$query = "
    SELECT wposts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta 
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
        AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'votes'
        AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
    ORDER BY CAST(wpostmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC";

$total_record = count($wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A));

$paged          = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_per_page  = get_option('posts_per_page');
$offset         = ($paged - 1)*$post_per_page;
$max_num_pages  = ceil($total_record/ $post_per_page);

$wp_query->found_posts   = $total_record;

// number of pages 
$wp_query->max_num_pages = $max_num_pages;

$limit_query = " LIMIT ".$post_per_page." OFFSET ".$offset; 

$result      = $wpdb->get_results($query.$limit_query,OBJECT);// return OBJECT

if($result):
foreach ($result as $post):
    setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
    <div class="navigation"><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?></div>
    <?php
endif;
```

Done!

Answer (score 2):

```
global $wp_query; 
// per page 
$ppp = $limit;
// full found posts , query without limit 
$wp_query->found_posts = count($total);
// number of pages 
$wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $ppp);
```

It Works!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

global $wpdb, $wp_query, $paged;

$author = isset($_GET['author_name']) ? get_userdatabylogin($author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
$post_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=' . $post_per_page);
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$offset = ($paged - 1) * $post_per_page;

$query = "SELECT `wp_postmeta`.*, `wp_posts`.* ";
$query .= "FROM `wp_postmeta` "; 
$query .= "LEFT JOIN `wp_posts` ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id "; 
$query .= "WHERE `meta_key` = 'autor' AND `post_status` = 'publish' AND `meta_value` = '%s' "; 
$postsQuery = $query . "LIMIT $offset, " . $post_per_page;

$numRowsQuery = $wpdb->prepare( $query, $author->id );
$allPosts = $wpdb->get_results($numRowsQuery); 
$wp_query->found_posts = $wpdb->num_rows;
$wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $post_per_page); 

$dataQuery = $wpdb->prepare( $postsQuery, $author->id );
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($dataQuery); 

?> 

<?php if ($posts) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```