# Custom WP_Query order by post_meta and (author) user_meta

Tags: php, custom-post-type, wordpress

I am having an issue that i couldn't find on google and elsewhere.
To put problem in the context.
I am making a wordpress site where user can put their tutor listing for giving a tutorials, and i am implementing the system of evaluation of the tutors them self and their listening.
So I have *tutor_listing* post type and each *tutor_listing* has a '*post_score*' meta value, and each tutor (user who puts his tutorials) has *user_meta* value called '*user_points*'.

So I need a **WP_Query** that will get from the database all published tutor_listing but **sorted by** (*post_score* **+** *user_points*). Just to emphasis '*post_score*' is a *post_meta* of the *post_type* *tutor_listing* and '*user_points*' is *user_meta* of author of that post (*tutor_listing*).
Also i need that value to show in the loop.

I can get all the tutor_listing by

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I can get the result from the custom wordpress sql query like this:

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.post_author, p1.post_title, p1.post_date, (um1.meta_value + pm1.meta_value) AS total_score
FROM $wpdb->posts p1
    JOIN $wpdb->users u1 ON (p1.post_author = u1.ID)
    JOIN $wpdb->usermeta um1 ON (um1.user_id = u1.ID)
    JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm1 ON (pm1.post_id = p1.ID)
WHERE p1.post_type = 'tutor_listing'
AND p1.post_status = 'publish'
AND um1.meta_key = 'user_points'
AND pm1.meta_key = 'post_score'";
```

Can WP_Query provide such a functionality?
I need WP_Query to use its all extra functionality like pagination ect.
Or is there a way i could all the result done with the my custom sql give to WP_Query object?

Thank you

Comment: I think you should be able to do that by specifying `meta_key` and then adding a `meta_query` to your `$args`. Check [this section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) out a bit, there is a ''orderby' with 'meta_value' and custom post type' part.

Comment: yes i could get the order by `post_meta` and i could make multiple `post_meta` like [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Getting_the_final_SQL) but i dont know how to get the value of the authors `user_meta` and add them together in the `total_score` and sort then by it

Comment: I need this functionality for the pagination.
But i found solution how to make `$wpdb` into `$wp_query` and do pagination that works.
Solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823834/paginate-wordpress-wpdb-query/24448092#24448092)